# Is $f_1: \pi_1(X \vee X) \rightarrow \pi_1(X)$ a surjection?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Suppose we have a space $X$
Does the following always hold?

> Does there exist a map $f: \pi_1(X \vee X) \rightarrow \pi_1(X)$ which is surjective?

---

More generally does

> Do there exist maps $f_1: \pi_1(X \vee Y) \rightarrow \pi_1(X)$ and $f_2:\pi_1(X \vee Y) \rightarrow \pi_1(Y)$ which are surjective?

this hold true?
I think the answer is yes by the SVK but I am not sure about it.

Comment: You know SVK doesn't always work (for all spaces).....

Comment: What are the maps $f_1,f_2$?

Comment: @Tyrone I have edited the question

Comment: From what I think the finite case is trivial if $\pi_1(X)$ is generated by $1$ generator then, then $\pi_1(X) \subset \pi_1(X \vee X)$ because (I cant frame the sentence...) the loops are the same and there could be more.... I know I can't express what I am thinking but still...

Comment: Well, $X$ and $Y$ are always retracts of $X\vee Y$ (and $\pi_1$ is a functor on the category of pointed spaces).

Comment: @Tyrone so there exist such maps even when they are generated uncountably (that is when they have uncountable generators)? Btw yes I think yes I thought about for some time and reached the conclusion that it does not matter when $\pi_1$ is literally a **functor** in   $\text{TOP}_{\text{pointed}}$

Comment: Yes, the maps always exist, and are induced by continuous maps of pointed spaces (I am assuming you intend to choose the basepoints in the obvious manner).

Comment: @Tyrone what is the obvious way? Although it won't matter as the spaces I am concerned about are path-connected

Comment: The retraction exists regardless of the choice of base-points.

Answer (score 2):

This is much simpler than applying the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem.

If you set things up correctly it's just an application of the functoriality properties of the fundamental group functor: By folding $X \vee X$ in half one gets a retraction from $X \vee X$ to the first $X$ factor of $X \vee X$, and now you can apply the fact that the induced $\pi_1$-homomorphism of a retraction is surjective.

In more detail, pick a base point $p \in X$ and represent $X \vee X$ as
$$X \vee X = (X \times \{p\}) \cup (\{p\} \times X) \subset X \times X
$$
with base point $P = (p,p) \in X \vee X$. Define an embedding
$$i : (X,p) \to (X \vee X,P) \quad i(x)=(x,p)
$$
and a projection
$$q : (X \vee X,P) \to (X,p) \quad q(x,y)=x
$$
Intuitively one is embedding $X$ as the "first" factor of $X \vee X$ and then one is retracting $X \vee X$ to that free factor, although formally it is easier to just define and use the embedding.

Since $q \circ i : (X,p) \to (X,p)$ is the identity, it follows that the composed induced group homomorphism is the identity:
$$(q \circ i)_* : \pi_1(X,p) \to \pi_1(X,p)
$$
Since $\pi_1$ is a functor, this homomorphism factors as
$$(q \circ i)_* : \pi_1(X,p) \xrightarrow{i*} \pi_1(X \vee X,P) \xrightarrow{q_*} \pi_1(X,p)
$$
Since the composition $(q \circ i)_* = q_* \circ i_*$ is surjective, it follows that the second factor $q_*$ is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

$X \vee Y$ is the one-point-union of the pointed spaces $X,Y$. It can represented as the quotient space

$$X \vee Y  = (X \times \{ 1\} \cup  Y \times \{ 2\}) / (\{x_0\} \times \{ 1\} \cup \{y_0\} \times \{ 2\} ) .$$

The map $i_X : X \to X \vee Y, i_X(x) = [x,1]$, is an embedding, similarly $i_Y : Y \to X \vee Y, i_Y(y) = [y,2]$.

Define $R_X : X \times \{ 1\} \cup  Y \times \{ 2\} \to X, R_X(x,1) =x, R_Y(y) = x_0$. This induces a map $r_X: X \vee Y \to X$ on the quotient having the property $r_X \circ i_X = id$. Thus $r_X$ is a retraction. Similarly we get a retraction $r_Y : X \vee Y\to Y$.

Now let $f_X = (r_X)_* : \pi_1(X \vee Y) \to \pi_1(X)$. Then $f_X \circ (i_X)_* = id$ which shows that $f_X$ is a surjection. Simlarly $f_Y = (r_Y)_* :  \pi_1(X \vee Y) \to \pi_1(Y)$ is a surjection.